# Process.Start() causing application to hang

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm having a hard time with `Process.Start()`
Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fileName = @"C:\path_to_project\bin\Debug\helloworld.exe";

    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName);
    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    info.RedirectStandardError = true;
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;

    Process process = Process.Start(info);
    string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    string returnvalue = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    process.WaitForExit();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The code should only call helloworld console application which has only one line `Console.WriteLine("Hello World")`, nothing special.

When I debug this code I reach the `Process process = Process.Start(info);` Then when I hit Step over (F10) nothing happens. My application hangs and the process I started is there but it is not finishing. I need to kill'em all.

This code works on my colleague's machine but on my machine the process just hangs and only thing I can do is kill the process.

I also noticed that when I double click any console application in explorer the cursor changes the state to busy and never changes back until I kill explorer.exe.

Could it be some security issue or malware?

Comment: If you have the source for helloworld.exe, try rebuilding it in Release mode as oppose to Debug. Your application may hang because of debugger being attached to the solution.
Also, try running your solution from where you're creating the process without debug (CTRL + F5) and see what happens.

Comment: Shouldn't `CreateNoWindow ` be set to false?

Comment: Same thing in Release mode and Start Withouth Debugging.

Comment: I don't want it to show the window only want the text which is printed in console.

Comment: Try this: Goto the menu by clicking icon in top-left corner of console window.
Goto "Properties"
On the Options tab, under "Edit Options," un-check "QuickEdit Mode"
Click "OK" and confirm that you would like to apply changes to all windows with same title.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski it is already unchecked. I restored console to defaults. Still the same.

Comment: Are yours and your colleagues environments on the same Domain with the same access restrictions? i.e. do you both have Administrator rights to your machines?  The path to your EXE may be a restricted folder under your user account - can you run Visual Studio as an administrator to try this out?

Comment: You'll have to get your machine healthy again first before you'll have a shot at getting this code working.  Uninstall Avast.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but worth observing. [`StandardOutput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx): "There is a similar issue when you read all text from both the standard output and standard error streams ... To avoid deadlocks, use asynchronous read operations on at least one of the streams"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ok, i didn't know that is all going to one stream. Good to know that.

Answer (score 2):

Avast Antivirus intercepts Process.Start(), probably it tries to sandbox the application i'm trying to start so it hangs.

I disabled shield temporary and it now works.

Thank you all for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

So actually your code looks fine. And it does work for me with a simple "Hello World!" console application.

However, I remember that we had a problem like this some time ago, with a hanging `process.WaitForExit()` on a process we tried to get the output from.

Unfortunatly I can't remember if it was exactly the same problem as you encounter here. But I suggest to try another possibility for what you are trying to achieve:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fileName = @"C:\path_to_project\bin\Debug\helloworld.exe";

    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName);
    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    info.RedirectStandardError = true;
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;

    StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder errorBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    Process process = new Process {StartInfo = info};
    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => outputBuilder.Append(e.Data);
    process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => errorBuilder.Append(e.Data);

    process.Start();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine(); // do this after process.Start()
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

    process.WaitForExit();

    string error = errorBuilder.ToString();
    string returnvalue = outputBuilder.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("Returned: {0}", returnvalue);
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", error);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I'm sorry that I cannot explain *why* your code is hanging (and as I said it's working for me). But maybe this variation will work.

Comment: It is problem with Avast Antivirus.

Comment: @user3522638 What do you mean? Your and my code actually both should work for any process that exits in time. If that Avast Antivirus process doesn't exit, that would explain your problem. But you said it also happens with a "Hello World!" app.

Comment: It happens with all console applications. I turned of the avast shields and it works now